# In a Kubernetes environment, the Kafka Streams application is currently experiencing Out-Of-Memory (OOM) issues

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In a Kubernetes environment, the Kafka Streams application is currently experiencing Out-Of-Memory (OOM) issues.

I can't identify where the memory usage of the pod is coming from.
I don't know the cause, so I need assistance.

---

- kafka streams version : 3.1.1
- pod limit memory setting value : 5Gi
- max java heap size setting value : 4Gi
- Usage Pod Memroy : 4.75GiB
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXsqh.png)
- Avg Heap Usage : 1.01GiB
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv7qt.png)
- Avg Non-Heap Usage : 221MiB
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk1wK.png)
- Avg GC Old Gen Size : 1GiB
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaD0n.png)

Ephemeral Storage Usage, Requests and Limits
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMeh5.png)

---

properties Code

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.METRICS_RECORDING_LEVEL_CONFIG, "DEBUG");
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_PRODUCTION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaStreamsExceptionHandler.class);
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, LogAndContinueExceptionHandler.class);

        properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, streamsName);
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
        properties.put("transactional.id.expiration.ms", 1500000000);
```

```
KTable<Windowed<String>, PayLoadDTO> multiplePayment =
                sourceStream.mapValues(PayLoadDTO::new)
                        .groupBy((key, value) -> value.getLoginFailureStreamDTO().getPayload().getLoginId(), Grouped.with(Serdes.String(),
                                PaymentSerdes.PayLoadDTOSerde()))
                        .windowedBy(TimeWindows.ofSizeAndGrace(Duration.ofMinutes(super.getWindowTime()), Duration.ZERO))
                        .reduce(PayLoadDTO::aggregate,
                                Materialized.<String, PayLoadDTO, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("device")
                                        .withKeySerde(Serdes.String()).withValueSerde(PaymentSerdes.PayLoadDTOSerde()));

        multiplePayment.toStream()
                .mapValues((key, value) -> createSinkDTO(value))
                .map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(String.valueOf(value.getPayload().getUid()), value))
                .to(super.getTopologyProperties().getSinkTopicName(), Produced.with(Serdes.String(), PaymentSerdes.PaymentSinkSerde()));
```

I would like to know the cause of excessive memory usage in the pod and how to resolve it.

Comment: How do you know kubernetes is the actual problem? Have you tried running your code just with `docker run`? Otherwise, I suggest you install JMX exporter and Prometheus in Kubernetes or otherwise take a heap dump to find the issue... Also, Kafka Streams stores data off heap. You need to look at the JMX metrics to get information about it

Comment: Hi, @OneCricketeer.
Thanks for commenting.
I want to see memtable numbers in Prometheus, but which metric should I look at?

1. kafka_streams_stream_state_metrics_memtable_bytes_flushed_total

2. kafka_streams_stream_state_metrics_size_all_mem_tables

Comment: "Size all mem tables" sounds useful to me. Also, you'll want to use RocksDB on a PVC / VolumeMount for your statestore, if you want to preserve memory